# Auto retarget PR branches in Microsoft Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am new to Microsoft Azure DevOps. I have extensively worked on bitbucket, gitlab etc.
In bitbucket, it used to happen like you have below-

```
PR#1 from Branch1 -> Branch2
PR#2 from Branch2 -> Branch3
```

In Bitbucket, if we merge PR2 (and check the checkbox to delete source branch) then automatically PR#1 used to retarget itself to Branch3. Also it used to keep the diff unchanged.

In ADO, we are facing issues where no retargeting is happening automatically. Despite checking the checkbox for source branch deletion on PR#2, it is retained by MS ADO. And after PR#2 is merged, PR#1 shows the changes of both PR#1 and PR#2 until we merge Branch3 into Branch1 manually and do the manual retargeting. And then we have to delete Branch2 manually (It could not be deleted because it had a PR#1 as target branch).

Does anyone know the way out here, I liked the bitbucket way of handling it but ADO seems missing this config.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature you stated is not supported in Azure DevOps.

If you really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: @lovegupta, Is there any update from you?